# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : authentication with AAD

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I'm recreating same of my .NET 6/.NET 7 Web APIs in .NET 8. I have an issue with the authentication using Swagger connected with Azure Active Directory. I have just copied the old code in the new project in .NET 8 and the behaviours is different.

In the `Program.cs` I added this code to read the Azure configuration from the `appsettings.json`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    },
    options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;
    });
```

And then in the Swagger configuration, I have

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);
    options.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);

    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    options.OperationFilter<AppendAuthorizeToSummaryOperationFilter>();

    var scope = configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Scopes");

    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Description = "The api is protected against Azure AD",
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(AuthorizationUrl),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
                    { scope, "Default Flow Scopes" } },
                TokenUrl = new Uri(TokenUrl),
            }
        }
    });

    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "oauth2"
                }
            },
            new[] { "Id", "Description" }
        },
    });
});
```

So, with this code in .NET 6 / .NET 7, when I open the Swagger documentation site, I can click on the button *Authorize*, I see the following screenshot:

[image]

The `_client_id_` is already inserted and the authentication is working. If I try an API, it is working as expected.

If I do the same with the .NET 8 version, the `_client_id_` is empty and the scopes are different.

[image]

So, I added the same `_client_id_` and select the scope. I can authenticate myself again the Azure Active Directory but when I try an API the request is rejected because the authentication is not valid.

> Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature is invalid"

[image]

### Update

As requests, this is the `.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer" Version="7.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OpenApi" Version="1.6.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="7.0.12" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Nerdbank.GitVersioning" Version="3.6.133" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And this one is the `appsettings.json` (without the keys)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/b4e49ba2-xxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientId": "d3de6da4-xxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxx",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Scopes": "User.Read",
    "TenantId": "b4e49ba2-xxx",
    "Audience": "api://544b368d-xxx",
    "TokenValidationParameters": {
      "ValidAudiences": [
        "api://3fb53476-xxx",
        "api://544b368d-xxx"
      ],
      "ValidIssuers": [
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/b4e49ba2-xxx/v2.0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I like to highlight that those settings are working in the projects based on NET6 and NET7.

Comment: seems that the token signature is not valid (old expired token?) or the signing key is not found?, I blogged about how to troubleshoot JwtBearer API problems at https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Can you please share your `.csproj` and `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the scope we test was different from the old one, could you try hard-coding the scope value like `api://client_id/User.Read` in your .net 8 project? I mean replace `var scope = configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Scopes");` with `api://544b368d-xxx/User.Read`.

Using `User.Read` would make the token generated with scope pointing to Ms graph API.

[image]

but using `api://xxx/api_name` would generate correct access token.

[image]

By the way, in the screenshot I could see that the old test used `api://d3de6da4-xxx/User.Read`, which mean the audience validated in the api project might be `d3de6da4-xxx`, but in the appsettings you shared set `544b368d-xxx` as the audience, do you create the new azure ad app for the authentication and exposed new API?

About why we don't have default value in the client id field: could you check whether you have configuration like below?

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.OAuthAppName("Swagger Client");
        options.OAuthClientId("client_id");
        options.OAuthClientSecret("client_secret");
        options.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
    });
}
```

[image]

Here's what I had in my side.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApplication1", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    {
                        "api://client_id/Tiny.Read", "API permission description"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "oauth2"
                },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "oauth2",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List < string > ()
        }
    });
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    //{
    //    options.OAuthAppName("Swagger Client");
    //    options.OAuthClientId("client_id");
    //    options.OAuthClientSecret("client_secret");
    //    options.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
    //});
}
```

appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "client_id",//because the api I exposed is also exposed by this app, so I don't need to define the audience
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  //"Scopes": "Tiny.Read",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```